# How can I generate below sequence using Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Sequence
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
and so on ……
```

Comment: Recursive cte perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
SQL> with temp (col) as
  2    (select level
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= &n
  5    )
  6  select col
  7  from temp cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                                           connect by level <= col
  9                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by col;
Enter value for n: 5
old   4:    connect by level <= &n
new   4:    connect by level <= 5

       COL
----------
         1
         2
         2
         3
         3
         3
         4
         4
         4
         4
         5
         5
         5
         5
         5

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking two recursive CTEs.  One to generate the counts and the other to generate the rows:

```
with cte(n) as (
      select 1
      from dual
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 6
     ),
     dups(nn, n) as (
      select 1 as nn, n
      from cte
      union all
      select nn + 1, n
      from dups
      where nn < n
     )
select *
from dups;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle 12 and above you can use `LATERAL` join. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=355798b570b8249f4b14b084f486aaee):

```
with gen as (
  select level as l
  from dual
  connect by level < 5
)
select l
from gen,
  lateral (
    select null
    from dual
    connect by level <= gen.l
  )
```

Comment: CTE example is more general in terms of database (solution works on any DB with support of recursive CTE) and version (Oracle supports recursive CTE from 11 or may be less). So think it should be the marked answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single recursive sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. a CTE) without any joins:

```sql
WITH items ( id, seq, max_seq ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE WHEN id < seq THEN id + 1 ELSE 1 END,
         CASE WHEN id < seq THEN seq ELSE seq + 1 END,
         max_seq
  FROM   items
  WHERE  id < max_seq
  OR     seq < max_seq
)
SELECT seq
FROM   items;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | SEQ |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> |   2 |
> |   2 |
> |   3 |
> |   3 |
> |   3 |
> |   4 |
> |   4 |
> |   4 |
> |   4 |
> |   5 |
> |   5 |
> |   5 |
> |   5 |
> |   5 |
> |   6 |
> |   6 |
> |   6 |
> |   6 |
> |   6 |
> |   6 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d368d330150858b734ead514d4bdef87)*